# CSS Media Query - Soft-keyboard breaks css orientation rules - alternative solution?

Tags: android, css, media-queries

I am working with multiple tablet devices - both Android <del>and iOS</del>. Currently I have following resolution variations for all the tablets.

- 1280 x 800
- 1280 x 768
- <del>1024 x 768 (iPad Obviously)</del> - iPad does not have this issue

Simplest way to apply device orientation based style is to use media query's orientation using following syntax.

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait)
{
  /* My portrait based CSS here */
}

@media all and (orientation:landscape)
{
  /* My landscape based CSS here */
}
```

This works perfectly fine on all tablet devices. **BUT**, the problem is, when device is in portrait mode and user taps on any input field (eg. search) the soft-keyboard pops up - which reduces the visible area of web page and forces it to render in landscape based css. On android tablet devices, it depends on keyboard's height.
So, ultimately the web page looks broken. Therefore, I can't use CSS3's orientation media query to apply styles based on orientation (unless there is better media query to target orientation). Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hossain/S5nYP/5/ which emulates this - for device testing use full test page - http://jsfiddle.net/S5nYP/embedded/result/

Here is a screenshot of the behaviour taken from the demo page.
[image]

So, is there any alternative to takle this issue, I'm open to JavaScript based solution if native CSS based solution does not work.

I found a snippet on http://davidbcalhoun.com/2010/dealing-with-device-orientation which suggests to add class on  and target based on that. For example:

```
<html class="landscape">
  <body>
    <h1 class="landscape-only">Element Heading - Landscape</h1>
    <h1 class="portrait-only">Element Heading - Portrait</h1>
    <!-- .... more... ->

# CSS
.landscape .landscape-only { display:block; }
.landspace .portrait-only  { display:none; }
.portrait .portrait-only   { display:block; }
.portrait .landscape-only  { display:none; }
```

What do you guys think about this? Do you have better solution?

Comment: Just found out, **iPad** does _NOT_ have this issue. ONLY android OS (honeycomb tablets) and mobiles has this issue.

Comment: I ran into a similar issue with my mobile website.  After testing across a couple Android devices, it doesn't seem to be limited to any specific OS or mobile/tablet device.  It looks like its primarily a problem with Motorola and Samsung devices.  I wasn't able to reproduce the issue on our HTC phone.

Comment: This issue is mainly with android devices, mobile/tablet - only way you can reproduce this is to install custom keyboard which has large height, so that, when the keyboard is showing, the available height for webview is less than available width. Only then, webview triggers orientation change. For example, in the screenshot, if I can disable the suggestion layer on top of keyboard, then this issue will not be there, because, webview height will be greater than width. But, anyway, I haven't got any elegant & efficient solution yet.

Comment: Just realize that IOS 7.0.0 fullscreen WebApp has this behaviour too

Comment: That's sad. I was not able to resolve the issue efficiently, hence marked it as `known limitation`.

Comment: [See this answer for the solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16852422/css-media-query-landscape-android-soft-keyboard)

Answer (score 111):

I know this is a couple of years late but I found a great solution

For landscape media:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* landscape styles here */}
```

And for portrait media:

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* portrait styles here */}
```

The full solution and why it works can be found here [Michael Barret - Android browser challenges](http://abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/)

Edit: this link is now expired, but a snapshot can be found on the internet archive: [Michael Barret - Android browser challenges](https://web.archive.org/web/20160509220835/http://blog.abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/)

Comment: It solves the issue, but creates more issues on other devices for me (mainly laptops and computers)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't work in all mobile devices.

Comment: @StephanBijzitter maybe you could use the 'max-width' property?

Comment: This solution is very rough and will not work on some devices. For example my phone gives about 17.7/9 when opening the soft keyboard, while the landscape aspect ratio is much less on many other devices.

Comment: the stupid thing about this whole media query that the browsers actually identify themselves, so y the hell aren't we provided with the information?????

Comment: Radical answer dude

Comment: The full solution link is broken.

Comment: Great! While orientation:landscape did not work, this solution did :)

Comment: This relies on current max-width of mobile devices and when improving technology these will changes. So should we change all media queries scenario? I think this is a poor idea.

Answer (score 29):

The problem lies in the way that orientation is calculated:

http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

> The ‘orientation’ media feature is ‘portrait’ when the value of the ‘height’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

Since the height/width is calculated on the visible viewport, the soft keyboard apparently causes the orientation to flip now that the viewport width is less than the height. One solution would be just to use your media queries based on just `width` instead. This makes it more flexible across devices regardless of orientation, not to mention width/height is more widely supported than orientation.

If you want to account for the width instead of orientation, I'll use the iPhone as an example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* rules applying to portrait */
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* rules applying to landscape */
}
```

This approach is more flexible than orientation since the queries aren't limited to devices/user-agents that support orientation, not to mention that orientation [tells you very little](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/the_orientation.html) versus the width.

Of course if you *really* need to know orientation, it seems like setting the class initially and just use that might be your best option.

Comment: I understand how landscape and portrait is calculated by the browsers. But, need alternative and better way of handling this. Another  interesting thing is, iPad does not trigger orientation change when keyboard is up. I don't know why the **** android had to implement that way.

Comment: I'm just curious as to why you specifically need the orientation of the device as opposed to just the width. What is the problem you're trying to solve that just the width alone won't fix?

Comment: I'm working with multiple device with different resolution. Could you please give example how width can be used as an alternative to orientation? About, use of orientation change, there are multiple application on orientation change - usually available space different in different orientation. So, some elements can be hidden or re-sized based on orientation. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @HossainKhan `@media all and (max-device-wdith:NNNpx){}` or `@media all and (min-device-wdith:NNNpx){}` or `@media all and (device-wdith:NNNpx){}`

Comment: I updated my answer. The device width should take orientation into account, so that when your orientation changes the width should update accordingly.

Comment: check out [this post](https://plus.google.com/103968640394430697195/posts/G4UihMKpXiV) on how to use this technique to help define your retina images

Comment: ultimately by removing `and (orientation:portrait)` and just applied the max and min width resolved my issue.!!!

Answer (score 16):

An alternative might be to use [`device-aspect-ratio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#device-aspect-ratio), which remains unchanged. However, in Webkit, rotating the device doesn't trigger an update of CSS rules using this query, even though JavaScript tests return true for the new aspect ratio. This is apparently [due to a bug](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/mediaqueries/deviceaspectratio.html), but I'm not able to find a bug report. Using a combination of `orientation` and `{min,max}-device-aspect-ratio` seems to work fine:

```
@media screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: portrait)
@media screen and (min-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (orientation: landscape)
```

The use of `orientation` triggers updates as expected, and the use of `device-aspect-ratio` restricts updated to actual changes of orientation.

Comment: Unfortunately this feature is deprecated now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/device-aspect-ratio

Comment: mid 2020 and this still works despite being deprecated...great solution, the only one that actually worked for me in all the cases I have!

Answer (score 6):

I worked through the options listed above and none quite fixed the issues for me. I switched to using screen.availHeight as it gives consistent height results avoiding the keyboard display issue.

```
// Avoiding the keyboard in Android causing the portrait orientation to change to landscape. 
// Not an issue in IOS. Can use window.orientation.
var currentOrientation = function() {
  // Use screen.availHeight as screen height doesn't change when keyboard displays.  
  if(screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth){
    $("html").addClass('portrait').removeClass('landscape'); 
  } else {
    $("html").addClass('landscape').removeClass('portrait'); 
  }
}

// Set orientation on initiliasation
currentOrientation();
// Reset orientation each time window is resized. Keyboard opening, or change in orientation triggers this.
$(window).on("resize", currentOrientation);
```

Comment: So I've been testing this a bit more and it's not so straight forward. Android devices need to use screen.availHeight and screen.availWidth. IOS is buggy with these though so use window.orientation for IOS. Desktop should use window.innerHeight, window.innerWidth as you want the window dimensions not the screen dimensions.

Comment: I've been bashing my head against the wall with the code above. Too finicky. I'm not supporting desktop for this app, so I'm using window.orientation is the magic solution for Android and IOS. Working fine now.          var orientation = Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90 ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';

Answer (score 5):

For me, this did the trick:

```
  @media screen and (max-device-aspect-ratio: 1/1), (max-aspect-ratio: 1/1){
        /*Portrait Mode*/
};
```

While `max-aspect-ratio` takes care of triggering Portrait mode simply by resizing the window (useful for PCs and other landscape-only devices), `max-device-aspect-ratio` helps with smartphones or other devices with variable orientation. And because I'm not declaring specific settings for Landscape mode, even if `max-aspect-ratio` is reporting >1 to the system, Portrait mode will still be triggered by `max-device-aspect-ratio` if the Android device is oriented that way.

The `1/1` part basically means that if the ratio is <=1, it goes to Portrait mode, otherwise it goes to landscape mode.

Comment: What about when the keyboard comes up?

Comment: When the virtual keyboard comes up on a mobile device, nothing changes, because the device's aspect ratio (max-device-aspect-ratio) only changes when you actually rotate the device or when you deliberately change the screen orientation from Portrait to Landscape and vice-versa.

Comment: Yes, I ended up implementing and testing it for myself. I'm developing a package around this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mobile-orientation

Comment: Came back to inquire over one more thing: `(max-aspect-ratio: 1/1)`. It seems we only need this bit to detect portrait on desktop?

Comment: Right. The 1/1 is to ensure that a perfect square still triggers portrait mode (which is possible in systems that allow window resizing, like a browser window on a desktop). Without it, weird things happen in this exact ratio.

Comment: I see. I only need to detect mobile, so I don't need this bit. Thanks.

Comment: Checking [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/device-aspect-ratio) reveals it's deprecated, which is unfortunate. The solution won't last, but can be used as a fallback test.

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/adi518/mobile-orientation) for the npm package I based around it.

Comment: This helped me to create my own selector, tested on windows/firefox+chrome, android, iPad:
`(max-aspect-ratio: 1/1), (orientation: portrait)`

Answer (score 1):

I've run through several of the answers above and none of them did exacly what i wanted, which is, to mimic iPhone functionality as closely as possible. The following is what is working for me in production now.

It works by assigning the window width and height of the device viewport to a data attribute for future checking. Since phones don't resize width when pulling up the keyboard, only the height, checking the ratio AND the width against the original width can tell you if the keyboard is up. I haven't found a use case this has failed yet, but I'm sure I will. If you all find one, please let me know.

I am using some globals, like InitialRun and MobileOrientation, which are used for js switching, I am also using html5 data-attributes to store info in the DOM for css manipulation.

```
    var InitialRun = true; // After the initial bootstrapping, this is set to false;
    var MobileOrientation = 'desktop';
    function checkOrientation(winW, winH){ // winW and winH are the window's width and hieght, respectively
        if (InitialRun){
            if (winW > winH){
                $('body').attr('data-height',winW);
                $('body').attr('data-width',winH);
                MobileOrientation = 'landscape';    
                $('body').attr('data-orientation','landscape'); 
            }
            else{
                $('body').attr('data-height',winH);
                $('body').attr('data-width',winW);
                MobileOrientation = 'portrait';
                $('body').attr('data-orientation','portrait');
            }
        }
        else{
            if (winW > winH && winW != $('body').data('width')){
                MobileOrientation = 'landscape';    
                $('body').hdata('orientation','landscape'); //TODO:uncomment
                $('body, #wrapper').css({'height':"100%",'overflow-y':'hidden'});
                //$('body').attr('data-orientation','portrait');
            }
            else{
                MobileOrientation = 'portrait';
                $('body').attr('data-orientation','portrait');
                $('body, #wrapper').css({'height':$('body').data('height'),'overflow-y':'auto'});
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a simple trick to solve this problem

```
@media (max-width: 896px) and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9){/* Landscape content*/}
```

I found max-width: 896px can be used for all mobile device. try this solution it works!

Comment: you save my day :), but when it comes back from landscape to portrait, zoom of the page is broken how to handle this?

Comment: This relies on current max-width of mobile devices and when improving technology these will changes. So should we change all media queries scenario?  I think this is a poor idea.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link: 
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/a-pixel-identity-crisis/
Relying not only on orientation, but also on  `max-device-height` or `device-pixel-ratio` may help. Anyway, I did not test it, so not sure that it'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Idea: Take the portrait parameter off of your media query and leave it only with a min-width. Do your normal styling for portrait mode in that media query. Then, create another media query for landscape mode with a min-height tall enough so that the the browser won't use that query when the keyboard pops up. You'd have to experiment with what this 'tall enough min-height' is, but it shouldn't be too hard since most (if not all) landscape modes have a height larger than you'd have when a keyboard pops up. Additionally, you could add a 'min-width' to the landscape query that is larger that most smart-phones in portrait view (i.e around ~400px) to limit scope of the query.

Here's an alternative (and tenuous) solution:
- Add an empty arbitrary element to your html that will have 'display: none' in anything other than portrait mode.
- Create a jquery or javascript listener for input:focus. When an input is clicked, your javascript checks the display property of the arbitrary element. If it returns 'block' or whatever you set it during portrait mode, then you can override your styling with JS to your portrait mode queries. Conversely, you'd have an input:blur listener to blank out the style.cssText properties of the elements you hard-coded.

I'm experimenting with this myself right now - I'll post code of what works when I get something solid and manageable. (My first solution seems the most reasonable).

Answer (score 0):

This works reliably for me. I am using http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ for the jQuery extension to detect $.browser.mobile.

```
if ($.browser.mobile) {
  var newOrientationPortrait = true;

//Set orientation based on height/width by default
  if ($(window).width() < $(window).height())
      newOrientationPortrait = true;
  else
      newOrientationPortrait = false;

//Overwrite orientation if mobile browser supports window.orientation
if (window.orientation != null)
    if (window.orientation === 0)
        newOrientationPortrait = true;
    else
        newOrientationPortrait = false;
```

Here is my code to modify the viewport based on orientation. This function is only called for mobile devices, not even tablets. This allows me to easily write CSS for 400px and 800px (Portrait vs Landscape).

```
_onOrientationChange = function() {
    if (_orientationPortrait) 
        $("meta[name=viewport]").attr("content", "width=400,user-scalable=no");
    else 
        $("meta[name=viewport]").attr("content", "width=800");
}
```

Due to the nature of my requirements I was not able to do this in CSS Media queries alone, since the DOM itself needed to change based on orientation. Unfortunately at my job, business people write software requirements without consulting development first.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same issue in iPad.
ie; when the soft keyboard appears in portrait mode, device is detected in landscape orientation and styles for landscape is applied to the screen, which resulted in a messed up view.

**Device Specification**

- *Device*: iPad Mini 4
- *OS*: iOS 11.2.6
- *Screen Resolution*: 1024 x 768

unfortunately, for me, this solution didn't worked.

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* landscape styles here */}
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* portrait styles here */}
```

So, what I did is, I've written a media query like this for my portrait mode.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 300px) and (max-width : 768px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* portrait styles, when softkeyboard appears, goes here */
}
```

ie; when the soft keyboard appears, the screen height reduces but screen width remains to 768px, which resulted in media query detecting screen as landscape orientation. Hence the work around given as above.

Answer (score 0):

Since iPhone 11 Pro Max Viewport is 414 x 896 PX - should be enough to have orientation: landscape with min-width: 500px