# What is the best practice with media-queries in CSS3?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm looking answers for some questions about CSS3 feature - **`Media Queries`**:

1. Which way is **better** (for browser due to the performance) for declaring css rules for different resolutions?

   ```
   //this in head:
   <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/Content/site1024.less" media="screen and (max-width: 1024px)" />

   //or this in css file:
   @media only screen and (max-width: 1024px){
       //styles here
   }
   ```
2. What is difference between **`max-device-width`** and **`max-width`**? Is it only rule addressed for mobile(`max-device-width`) or desktop(`max-width`) browsers?
3. If I write media query rule for tablet with resolution `1280x800` where user can also use portrait/landscape mode, how should it look? I should write rules for `max-width: 800px` and `max-width: 1280px` or there is another way?
4. If I write rules I should write something like this:

   ```
   <link ... media="only screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)... />
   ```

   or instead this two:

   ```
   <link ... media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px) ... />
   <link ... media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) ... />
   ```

---

*P.S. Please excuse any spelling or grammatical mistakes, English isn't my first language* 
*P.S.S. Before I posted this question I spend a while to search on stackoverflow and didn't find information about this question. If I was wrong and there is similar question I will delete my post.*

Comment: Try to split this into 4 questions, individually they can be answered much better.

Comment: There is some documentation on [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2FMedia_queries)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Rules in css file to reduce number of requests (better for performance).
2. 

- `max-width` is the width of the target display area
- `max-device-width` is the width of the device's entire rendering area

3. 

The another way I know to target portrait or landscape is to add `orientation` like this:

```
/* portrait */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* styles here */
}

/* landscape */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width: 768px) 
and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* styles here */
}
```

4. 

To define a stylesheet for mobile devices with a width between 320 and 480 pixels you have to write:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px)" href="mobile.css">
```

Comment: Also which resolutions are most popular. I mean for tablets, phones, desktops. Is any trends in this situation?

Comment: Ask to StatCounter http://gs.statcounter.com/#mobile_resolution-ww-monthly-201208-201301-bar (loading can be slow)

Answer (score 0):

I'am searching for good information about best practices in responsive design and I'll give you an advice.

In [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut) the developer get into a problem when he use CSS portrait condition and make the keyboard appears when he choose a input text of the document. I'm not sure why but it breaks the portrait condition.

In [This website](https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/) you can find information about better practices when you are creating media query's which I think are the best. Personaly I'll use the Exclusive type of media query in my website.

But by the other hand you could follow [This site](http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/) recomendations. I think that they are right but I prefer to create and use popular device dimentions media query's by myself.

Here is the list:

- < 480px (which applies to older, smaller smartphone screen sizes)
- < 768px, which is ideal for larger smartphones and smaller tablets
- > 768px, which applies for everything bigger such as large tablet screens and desktops screens.

Also, these can be used too if you've got the energy and time:

- <320px, which is great for older small, low res phones
- > 1024px stylesheet for wide screens on desktops.

I hope it help you.