# CSS responsive design - detect portrait display

Tags: css, responsive-design, landscape, portrait, landscape-portrait

I know it's with pure CSS possible to adapt the stylesheet according to screen dimensions, like this:

```
@media (max-width: 959px) {
  /* styles for smallest viewport widths */
}

@media (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 959px) {
  /* styles for mid-tier viewport widths */
}

@media (min-width: 960px) {
  /* original CSS styles */
}
```

<sup>([source](http://webstandardssherpa.com/reviews/responsive-retrofitting/))</sup>

Is it with **pure css** possible to check on a landscape or portrait display?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, using the following syntax:

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

See the [w3 specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation) for more information.

Comment: Thanks! Small follow-up question: what will happen when someone tilts his phone screen so that the orientation changes? Will the applied CSS change?

Comment: I haven't checked myself but I'm pretty certain that's the case since other media queries (such and screen width) are re-checked.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [orientation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation):

```
@media all and (max-width: 959px) and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation):

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers are incorrect. Android will swap from portrait to landscape when the keyboard is shown.

Different keyboards also need testing as they can take up more vertical space. Swift keyboard takes up more vertical space so you cannot use solutions like `@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) { /* landscape styles here */}` as this will fail on lots of phones.

The only solution is to use javascript.

On newer Android devices you can test and use the new window.screen.orientation api.

On iOS you can use window.orientation which works fine. ie `Math.abs( window.orientation ) === 90` is landscape

And as a fallback you can use `window.screen.width > window.screen.height` which will cover really old Android devices which don't support the new window.screen.orientation api

Then all you need to do is add / remove a class on resize / orientationchange events.

```
/* Android Orientation */
    var orientation = window.screen.orientation || window.screen.mozOrientation || window.screen.msOrientation || null;

    /* Check */
    if ( orientation && orientation.type ) {

        /* Landscape */
        if ( orientation.type === 'landscape' || orientation.type === 'landscape-primary' || orientation.type === 'landscape-secondary' ) {
            return 'landscape';

        /* Portrait */
        } else {                                
            return 'portrait';
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide some examples/ research in support of your answer?

Comment: Here are the issues about the breakpoints firing when the keyboard appears.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut/8883535

Comment: @kingJulian I do not need to provide research. When the keyboard shows on Android, the viewport resizes. They means breakpoints will change.

Comment: But you just did.. You provided an example in code whereas in your original post you didn't have any. Right?

Comment: @kingJulian The response was about providing research about the Android webview resizing when the keyboard is shown. I did add a link showing other people recognising the issue. Sorry I didn't realise this was after your original message. The example I just added was just to stop other people having to search for an Android solution.