# What's the best way to detect orientation using CSS media queries?

Tags: mobile, screen-orientation

What's the most reliable way to detect a device's orientation using CSS @media queries?

I tried these:

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait)
@media screen and (orientation: landscape)
```

but they don't work in all cases. [On some Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut), showing the keyboard in portrait mode can make it use the "orientation: landscape" query, since the aspect ratio is more than 1/1.

I've seen [suggestions](http://abouthalf.com/development/orientation-media-query-challenges-in-android-browsers/) to use this instead:

```
@media screen and (max-aspect-ratio: 13/9) // portrait
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9) // landscape
```

But these doesn't work on PhoneGap on the iPad; you need a ratio of something more like 12/9. And I'm a little concerned about targeting such a specific ratio, since there might be devices whose landscape mode is less than that ratio.

So is there a more reliable way to test this? (I'm only looking for a CSS @media query, not a JavaScript solution.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd still like to find a CSS-only solution, but I thought of a way to use JavaScript to generate the @media queries.

Assuming you can already detect orientation changes correctly using JavaScript, you can dynamically generate a `style` tag with the appropriate rules. When you do, and you're in portrait mode, add a width constraint to the queries, based on the current document's width. For example:

```
var portraitQuery, landscapeQuery;
if (currentOrientation === "portrait") {
    portraitQuery = "@media (orientation: portrait)"
        + " or ((orientation: landscape)"
            + " and (max-width: " + (window.innerWidth) + "px))",
    landscapeQuery = "@media (orientation: landscape)"
        + " and (min-width: " + (window.innerWidth + 1) + "px)";
} else {
    portraitQuery = "@media (orientation: portrait)";
    landscapeQuery = "@media (orientation: landscape)";
}
```

Then when the orientation changes, re-generate these queries. The idea is that, if you're in portrait mode and the @media orientation changes to landscape, it won't start using the "landscape" query unless the width also increases. This shouldn't happen if you're only showing the keyboard.

I'm not sure how reliable this is, but it's working for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a pro with orientation but maybe you can have both conditions for the landscape orientation like:

```
@media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 13/9), screen and (orientation:landscape)
```

Comment: I think the orientation queries are just checking the aspect ratio is greater or less than 1/1, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: JW is right, the logic suggested is the same as just checking orientation:landscape.