# Website turns to landscape with keyboard

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, keyboard, landscape-portrait

I've ran into an interesting problem. On my website I have two versions of navigation bar for mobiles - landscape and portrait. To detect these two I use CSS media orientation.

```
@media (orientation: landscape)
 {
  /* inline menu */ 
 }

@media (orientation: portrait)
 {
  /* multiple rows menu */
 }
```

However, when I open my keyboard page turns into landscape, because the actual page size becomes smaller.
 Can someone help me how to fix this? All I can think about is *focus* event on inputs, so whenever they're focused the portrait manu is turned on, but it would change the menu even on landscape.
Here's an illustrative image
[image: Portrait/Landscape/Portrait with keyboard]

Thanks!

Comment: Post your media definitions. Do you really need to check orientation/height? Width is usually enough.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by checking width. I find my way (added to post) the easiest detection possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check [Media Queries W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation)

You will find this interesting sentence:

> The ‘orientation’ media feature is ‘portrait’ when the value of the
>   ‘height’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the
>   ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

So, when the keyboard is opened, your page turn into landscape mode.

There are multiple ways to overcome this problem, you can
check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should ignore the height/orientation completely. Something like this:

```
@media (max-width: 480px)
 {
  /* inline menu */ 
 }

@media (min-width: 481px)
 {
  /* multiple rows menu */
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to. I use EMs and %s as units for the navigation bar so I don't want to mess with pixels.

Comment: So use EMs instead? Still, forget height.

Comment: I don't care about neither height nor width. I use _orientation_ media query. Cause if some tablet would be wider than 480px in portrait, your sollution would show landscape even in portrait, if you know what I mean. And that's not what I want.