# Angular 2 - Add / remove class by class name

Tags: angular

In my app I'm going to add or remove a class based on the device orientation. So if the app is portrait things would remain as it is. If it's landscape, then a class should get added.

I know I can easily do this with [class.ClassName] -

```
<div class="parentclass" [class.landscapeClass]="makeTrue">
 <span></span>
</div>
```

But the problem is I will have to repeat this change in several templates.

How can I can easily add and remove a class (`landscapeClass` in my example) wherever another class (`parentclass`) is used? And remove it when the app is portrait.

I'm getting the orientation of the app using the [cordova screen orientation plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation).

I'm using Angular2 RC4 and I'm looking for solution without having to use Jquery.

EDIT: The reason I'm trying to find a solution like this is because using media queries messes up my UI when the keyboard comes up on Android. I'm aware of the work around using aspect-ratio but it's not a 100% reliable solution.

Comment: What does "wherever another class (parentclass) is used?" mean? If a class is added somewhere on a parent element, then do ...? I don't think there is a way, at least not a feasible one.

Comment: Hi @GünterZöchbauer. What I mean is if the device is landscape, wherever the class "parentClass" is used, the class "landscapeClass" should get added. So in landscape it would be <div class="parentClass landscapeClass">. When it's portrait <div class="parentClass">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the class is only there to adjust the styling of the elements, you can use css media queries to check for portrait orientation instead of adding a class.

```
@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {}
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

EDIT: You can also put the class on a more global element and begin your selectors with the orientation glass.

CSS:

```
.orientationPortrait .parentClass { /* styling */}
```

Sass:

```
.parentClass {
  .orientationPortrait & { /* styling */}
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm trying to set styles by adding a class is because the media queries are messing up mu UI when the keyboard comes up on Android. :( Sorry. I should mention it in my question.

Comment: I've found a question dealing with that issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut

Comment: Yeah. But they say it doesn't work for all mobile devices. :( I need a solution where I can be a 100% sure.

Comment: You could then approach it differently: Only add the class once on a more global element.Then in your selectors simply start with the orientation class. Eg CSS: .orientationPortrait .parentClass { /* styling */ }

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Can you add it as an edit to your answer so I can mark it :)