# Zurb Foundation 5 - mobile landscape view

Tags: mobile, zurb-foundation, landscape

I am using Zurb Foundation 5 for my project, I compiled the stylesheet using the default SASS build command. 
I would like to know, is it possible to show different layouts on mobile landscape mode and portrait mode without using "show-for-landscape / show-for-portrait" classes? but just using "small-x/medium-x/large-x" classes?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-6 medium-4 large-4">A</div>
    <div class="columns small-6 medium-8 large-8">B</div>
</div>
```

My mobile (Samsung note 2, resolution = 720 x 1280 pixels) always showing the "small" styling when viewing the above example (No matter using the landscape or portrait mode)

FYI, I have added

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

on the document already

According to the link http://tech.bluesmoon.info/2011/01/device-width-and-how-not-to-hate-your.html, it stated that width=device-width will always return the device portrait width, is it the reason why zurb foundation 5 always gives me the "small" styling?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using media queries.

```
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

[CSS media queries is it possible to detect portrait / landscape tablet mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735467/css-media-queries-is-it-possible-to-detect-portrait-landscape-tablet-mode)