# Differentiating portrait and landscape versions in media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I've got these media queries set. But how do I edit this to have separate media queries set for the portrait, landscape versions (e.g.: iPad, iPhone)?

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 1824px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1823px) {}    

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px) {}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735467/css-media-queries-is-it-possible-to-detect-portrait-landscape-tablet-mode

Comment: @PhilipDernovoy thanks. But I can not fit the `and (orientation:portrait)` into my css. Coz for an example neither `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {}` or `@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {}`  can be used for a iPad (1024x768) landscape version.

Comment: Maybe that can help you https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: @PhilipDernovoy thanks. If I use `media (max-width: 1024) and (orientation: landscape) {}` wont that affect the existing media query for large desktops and laptops `@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1823px) {}`  ?

Comment: It won't affect coz `max-width: 1024px` and `min-width: 1200px` not intersect. And you must specify units of measure in your rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to add `orientation: portrait` and `orientation: landscape` to your media screen.

> iPad Landscape and Portrait

```
/* iPad Portrait */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: portrait) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

/* ur CSS */
}

/* iPad Landscape */
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 768px) 
  and (max-device-width: 1024px) 
  and (orientation: landscape) 
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {

}
```

> For latest iPads use pixel ratio:2 (Retina display) .

```
-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2
```

> Similarly for iPhone's, for iPhone's you have to set media for 4 different screens , < iPhone 4S , iPhone 5S and iPhone 6 and 6 plus versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and ( orientation: portrait ) {}

@media only screen and ( orientation: landscape) {}
```

I think thats what you are looking for.

Edit:

I think by *fit in to my css* you mean this:

```
@media (max-width: whatever) and (orientation: landscape) {}
```

If you are asking for a suggestion that when to use `portrait` or `landscape`, then use `landscape` when width of viewport is more and vice versa.

`max-width: 1024px` will set an upper limit and it will not interfere with rules for range: 1200px-1823px.

Comment: thanks I know I could use the and `orientation:` to do this but my questions is how do I fit it into my css? example iPad is 1024x768, so there should I use the `and ( orientation: landscape)` or `and ( orientation: portrait )` without affecting the desktop / laptop versions?

Comment: @Becky the format is width x height, so 1024x768 mean width is more. So you should use `landscape`

Comment: So if I do `media (max-width: 1024) and (orientation: landscape) {}` wont that affect the existing media query for large desktops and laptops `@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1823px) {} ` ?

Comment: @Becky i guess it will (not sure to what extent).

Comment: That's exactly my question. How do I cope with this situation?

Comment: @Becky I was wrong. `max-width: 1024px` wont interfere with `min-width: 1200px and max-width: 1823px`, as `max-width: 1024px` sets an upper limit and its not in range of 1200-1823