# Set viewport for landscape mode only

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design, viewport, landscape

I'm finishing my website and everything works perfectly except for one little thing. When I'm using my iPhone, the portrait mode is exactly as I want it, the problem is the landscape mode. I is like I've design it, but I don't like the final version... So I need to insert another line of code, but I don't know how to do it...
This is the one I have right now
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Now I need one just for the landscape mode. I want this one ^ to work all the time, except on landscape mode. On landscape mode I want this one:
`<meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height,initial-scale=1">`

My problem is how do I say that this should only work on landscape mode?

Thanks

Comment: "the landscape mode is exactly as I want it, the problem is the landscape mode"?

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad or you could use media queries: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735467/css-media-queries-is-it-possible-to-detect-portrait-landscape-tablet-mode

Comment: *portrait mode is exactly as I want it