# How to force rotate of the screen in web site

Tags: javascript, html, css, device-orientation

I have build a web site. If a device (smartphone or tablet) visit it, the system redirect the device in another page (version for mobile) m_index.aspx.

Now I want to force all device (smartphone or tablet) to sho my web site in landscape mode. It is possibile to rotate the screen automatically before it open some page?

regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34612485/set-viewport-for-landscape-mode-only

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only

Answer (score 1):

```
body { display:block; }
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
  body {  
    height: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (body {  
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
     transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

I used this time ago, if you don't like my method google searching return lots of answers

Comment: If I try to use your code into my css file, I have an error in the second point #only screen and (body....

Comment: post your html with some css and then we can see whats going wrong

Comment: Because there is a syntax error: `@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {`, body on the next line. I'm not sure if targeting the landscape is even needed.