# How to detect landscape mode and hide html content using css, queries or js

Tags: html, css, web, landscape

In my responsive website I want to control the way the website is viewed in mobile devices, and forbid viewing from landscape mode.

I searched through the stackoverflow site and found the option of putting a warning message.

I tried the css code below but it didn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

```
@media screen and  (max-width: 980px) and (orientation:portrait){
    #warning-message { 
        display:none; 
    }
}

@media screen and  (max-width: 980px) and (orientation:landscape){
    .content { 
        display:none; 
    }
    .mobile {
        display:none; 
    }
    #warning-message { 
        display:block; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735467/css-media-queries-is-it-possible-to-detect-portrait-landscape-tablet-mode

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/fppvbt0v/

Answer (score 1):

The ‘**orientation**’ media feature is ‘**portrait**’ when the value of the ‘**height**’ media feature is greater than or equal to the value of the ‘width’ media feature. Otherwise ‘orientation’ is ‘landscape’.

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

Source : https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation