# Browser support for orientation (portrait and landscape)

Tags: css, media-queries

What is the browser support for the following?

CSS to detect screen orientation:

```
 @media screen and (orientation:portrait) { … }
 @media screen and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

The CSS definition of a media query is at http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#orientation

From [How to detect the device orientation using CSS media queries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735467/how-to-detect-the-device-orientation-using-css-media-queries?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I've looked at Can I Use. But it says it is only supported for 48% of users in the UK. Is that correct? Or am I looking at the wrong thing? I'm not interested in `Screen.orientation` or anything fancy. I just want to use different styles when the viewport is taller than it is wide.

EDIT: I think that orientation is part of the core media query and is therefore widely supported (around 98%), see https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: 98% support for media queries, but when I looked up "orientation" on Can I Use the only thing I could find was "Screen Orientation" which is around 50%. So we think "orientation" comes under "media queries" and is widely supporterd?

Comment: It won't be IE 8 it will be carrier pigeons and smoke signals!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to set style sheet rules for landscape, square-like, and portrait layouts, when window width is not sufficient.

This example uses 7 and 8, so the 'square' styles are applied when the width and height are within 1/8th of each other's size. Using 9 and 10 will apply 'square' styles when the width and height are within 1/10th of each other. You must use numbers without decimals.

The code snippet works best in full-page view.

```css
div {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align:center;
  }

  #instructions {
    display:block;
    top:25%;
  }


  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 8/7) and (min-aspect-ratio: 7/8) {
    /* rules for square-ish layout */
    #square {
      display:block;
    }
  }

  @media (min-aspect-ratio: 8/7) {
    /* rules for landscape layout */
    #landscape {
      display:block;
    }
  }


  @media (max-aspect-ratio: 7/8) {
    /* rules for portrait layout */
    #portrait {
      display:block;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div id="portrait">
  Portrait
</div>
<div id="square">
  Square
</div>
<div id="landscape">
  Landscape
</div>
<div id="instructions">
  Resize your window to change the aspect and apply different style rules
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Support for [`orientation` in media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40media/orientation) looks like it's scarce at best according to the MDN. I'd advise against using them for critical responsiveness but might be handy as an experimental feature to test with.

**Desktop support:**

[image: Desktop browser support]

**Mobile support:**

[image: Mobile browser support]

Comment: Yes I saw that. I'm confused. Tim suggests support is 98%.

Comment: That's for the core Media Queries specification. The orientation feature is separate and so the 98% support figure is incorrect.

Comment: This suggests that orientation is part of teh core Media Queries and therefor well supported https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: It's part of the overall core specification for media queries, but is a separate implementation, an extension so to speak of it. That page lists everything currently available, but each individual feature has it's own compatibility requirements.

Comment: I'm not convinced. Support for media queries is wide and I think 'orientation' is part of that. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Browser_compatibility